# Server-Client in C prob

Tags: c, sockets, file-upload, segmentation-fault

I have two programs. One is the client and the other one is the server. The protocol used for communication must be like HTTP, but with file transfer, GET File. The problem lies within a client's function which reads the headers that the server sent(the server sends it perfectly). The headers will be like this:

```
404 *error code etc*  
MODE GET *get head unknown*  
AM 2969 *always the same*  
FILE *NAME*  
SIZE *sizeofthefile*  
END_HEADER
```

Then that function must read the `recv`ed buffer line-by-line and, using `sscanf`, read the values of the header into a struct that is passed as a pointer. The problem is that no matter how much I try to edit and experiment with the code to see what's wrong, I am overwhelmed with segfaults.

```
void getheader(int sock,head_in*inheader)  
{  
    char n[10];  
    int c;  
    int k=0;  
    char buffer[101];  
    if(recv(sock,buffer,100,0)<=0) serror("Error recving\n",sock);  
        c=strlen(buffer);  
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
    {    
        int w=0;
        for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            if((buffer[j+k]=='\n')&&(buffer[j+k]!='\0')) break;
            w++;
        }

        char *line=(char*)malloc(w+1);
        for(int j=0;j<w;j++)
        {
            line[j]=buffer[j+k];
        }
        k=k+w+1;

        if(i==0) sscanf(line,"%d ",&inheader->code);
        if(i==1) sscanf(line,"%s %s",n,inheader->mode);
        if(i==2) sscanf(line,"%s %d",n,&inheader->am);
        if(i==3) sscanf(line,"%s %s",n,inheader->name);
        if(i==4) sscanf(line,"%s %d",n,&inheader->size);

        free(line);
    }                                               
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Using one will help you spot the exact line where the segfault occurred.

Comment: Is your `c` initialised before executing `for(int j=0;j<c;j++)` ?